# Special and chunked data while parsing doc file

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, resume

Following is the code that I am using 
but issue is that there is unwanted data coming while using this code ..

The data is shown in Image attached below
Can anyone have the same issue before ,,
I need to aceept frst line.. but this data stopping to do the same..

```
private void ReturnParsedValues(string resumePath)
{
    // var strName = "";

    var path = resumePath;
    string html = File.ReadAllText(path);
    StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        String line = "";
        line = sr.ReadLine();  //) != null)
        lines.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
        html = lines.ToString();

        string objPlainText = lines.ToString();
        string[] Name = objPlainText.Split(' ');
        string FirstName = Name[0];
        string[] objLastName = Name[1].Split('\r');
        string LastName = objLastName[0];

    }


   GetName(html);
    GetEmail(html);
    getPhone(html);
    zipcodeGetter(html);

}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Word `doc` files are binary files - you're not supposed to read them line by line. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Actualy I want extract the characters only ,, and from first two characters i want to get the name.. that is my aim ,, but IDK how to discard these special characters @MathiasR.Jessen